# How can I find which module driver holds of i2c address?

Tags: kernel-modules

I want to communicate over a I2C bus using Python. But the address cannot be used because it is used by another driver.

```
# i2cdetect -y 0
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --    

# i2cget -y 0 0x1b
Error: Could not set address to 0x1b: Device or resource busy
```

I've followed in instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17836665/1073222).

```
# cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-001b/modalias 
wm8731
```

According to the author of that answer wm8731 is "*the name of the kernel driver that is keeping this device busy*". Disabling this module does not work:

```
# rmmod wm8731
Error: Module wm8731 is not currently loaded
```

How do I disable the driver for this address?

Comment: A driver is not necessarily a module and therefore can't necessarily be unloaded.  It's seems unlikely that this would be built in unless you are using a kernel made for a specific SoC.

Comment: Can you provide additional details about the specific system? Maybe you'd be able to get more input.

Comment: @ILMostro_7: The question is from 2014 ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to rebuild your kernel after disabling that driver from the kernel source code which is in kernel config file